# How to mock supabase APi select requests in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, supabase, supabase-js

I use supabase for my express js backend.
This is how I have defined my supabase client:

```
const config = require('../config/env');
const supabase = require('@supabase/supabase-js');
const supabaseClient = supabase.createClient(
  config.supabase.url,
  config.supabase.key,
  {
    auth: {
      autoRefreshToken: false,
      persistSession: false,
      detectSessionInUrl: false,
    },
  }
);

module.exports = supabaseClient;
```

An example call to the database can be something like this:

```
 const query = supabaseClient
    .from('items')
    .select('*')
    .eq('id', id);


  const { data, error } = await executeWithRetry(async () => await query);
```

I am writing some tests to test this logic and I would like to mock the supabase calls. This is my jest mock for supabase:

```
jest.mock('@supabase/supabase-js', () => {
  return {
    createClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        from: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        select: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
          eq: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          in: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          is: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          order: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          gte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          lte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          execute: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return Promise.resolve({
              data: [{ id: 'some-uuid-text' }],
              error: null,
            });
          }),
        })),
      };
    }),
  };
});
```

and this is the test

```
describe('userPermissions', () => {
  it('should fetch user permissions', async () => {
    const email = 'test@example.com';
    const result = await userPermissions({ email });
    expect(result).toEqual([{ role_id: 'mockedRoleId' }]);
  });
});
```

The `userPermissions`  method has a query that attempts to fetch data from supabase which keeps on responding with `undefined` data and `undefined` error. My expectation is that it should respond with what's in my execute part of the mock

```
return Promise.resolve({
              data: [{ id: 'some-uuid-text' }],
              error: null,
            });
```

What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The logic that I was using seemed correct but supabase doesn't have the execute function as part of its functions that's why the supabase calls were not responding with any response because I wasn't passing any data or error.
Updating the mock with `data` and `error` to this fixes the issue:

```
jest.mock('@supabase/supabase-js', () => {
  return {
    createClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        from: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        select: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
          eq: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          in: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          is: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          order: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          gte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          lte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          data: [
            {
              id: 'mockedRoleId',
              org_users: [{ id: 'mockUserId', status: 'active' }],
            },
          ],
          error: null,
        })),
        update: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
          eq: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          in: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          is: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          order: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          gte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          lte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          data: [
            {
              id: 'mockedRoleId',
              org_users: [{ id: 'mockUserId', status: 'active' }],
            },
          ],
          error: null,
        })),
      };
    }),
  };
});
```

To make the mocks more reusable, I went with a variant where I could define the expected data for every test, as seen below:

```
jest.mock('@supabase/supabase-js', () => {
  let testData = [
    {
      id: 'mockedRoleId',
      org_users: [{ id: 'mockUserId', status: 'active' }],
    },
  ];

  return {
    createClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        from: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        select: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
          eq: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          in: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          is: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          order: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          gte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          lte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          data: testData, // Use the data variable here
          error: null,
        })),
        update: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
          eq: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          in: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          is: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          order: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          gte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          lte: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          data: testData, // Use the data variable here
          error: null,
        })),
      };
    }),
    setTestData: (newData) => {
      testData = newData;
    },
  };
});
```

This is how the mock is used in the actual tests:

```
describe('activateUser', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const { setTestData } = require('@supabase/supabase-js');
    setTestData([]);
  });

  test(
    'should throw in error when no active user exists',
    async () => {
      const userEmail = 'no-invitation@example.com';
      const userProfileId = 'some-random-uuid';
      const tenantId = 'some-random-uuid';

      expect(() => {
        activateUser({ userProfileId, userEmail, tenantId });
      }).toThrowError('User does not exist');
    }
  );

  it('should activate user account', async () => {
    const { setTestData } = require('@supabase/supabase-js');
    setTestData([
      {
        id: 'mockedRoleId',
        org_users: [{ id: 'mockUserId', status: 'active' }],
      },
    ]);
    const userEmail = 'test@example.com';
    const userProfileId = 'ab3b2cb0-c032-42d8-b1d2-c78de679189f';
    const tenantId = 'a76b1802-0acb-4e9c-a157-d4c8239f6c2a';

    activateUser({ userProfileId, userEmail, tenantId });
  });
});
```